# Where is the Old One?

Tags: video-games, demons-souls

In the video game Demon's Souls, you must face the Old One, who is presumably the entity mentioned in the opening:

> On the second day, upon Earth was planted an irrevocable poison
>
> A soul-devouring demon

As this text appears on the screen, we see a beach with a distinctive rock formation, covered with hooded figures.

> In the game's ending, we see this beach in person when we descend below the Nexus to finally face the Old One. I'm assuming it's the same beach because the same rock formation can be seen. My question is, do we know where this place is? It seems meaningless to simply say it's 'below the Nexus', because the Nexus seems to be primarily a metaphysical construct, and anyway we don't know where the Nexus is either (do we?).

I realise this question probably doesn't have a straight answer, but it would be nice to shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I hate to say it, the '[End Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCM7A.png)' level in Demon's Souls is **literally**
 below the Nexus.

You jump into a great big damn hole and land on the floor below. Heck, even the official [Demon's Soul Wiki](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/end-game) describes the level as "Below the Nexus", as does the [Official Player's Guide](http://www.atlus.com/spoils/d.html)

[image: Below the Nexus]

Out-of-universe, you can see that the game level is *physically* the lowest level of the gamespace with nothing below it.